# linear gradient + background-size is not working in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css, webkit, gradient

Im using a linear gradient with a background-size of 400%. this allows me to animate between gradients  on hover and active state by changing the background-position. It works great in webkit but not in firefox. It seems as though the background-size property is not acknowledged at all.

Firefox is basically just squeezing the whole gradient in the element as if background-size is set to 100%.

Ive got a super simple page that demonstrates the problem:

http://firefoxgradient.s.cboo.st

(switch b/w firefox and webkit to see the difference)

Im using all the proper vendor prefixes for gradients and background-size.

I tinkered around with background-size on an image and it behaved as expected. Might be a gradient specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that in firefox `background-size` has two values one for the width and one of the height. If you do it like this: `background-size: 400%` firefox translates it to `background-size: 400% auto`. The auto is the value for the height. To fix it just write:
`-moz-background-size: 400% 400%`
this works for me.

Comment: that was it, so obvious. webkit spoils us.

Comment: What WebKit does is just not follow the spec, which is at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size and pretty clear about how a single value in background-size should work.  Of course you may be using the prefixed version there, which can legitimately not follow the spec....