# Background-size will not change height of (on left side) linear gradient in Firefox

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

When I put the following background image:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 1px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%) !important;
```

and the following background size:

```
background-size: 1000px 100px !important;
```

The background-size's width gets acknowledged, but the height does not, and the height just stays the same, no matter WHAT value I put in. It could be 999999px, it could be 50%, it could be 0px, all of those would result in the height still being 100%. Please help.

Comment: Give an online link or fiddle. It will help us to understand the real problem.

Comment: Can you please refer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523559/linear-gradient-background-size-is-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS, This has been tested in firefox and height works as expected...

```
 #yourid
 {
 width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), rgba(0,    0,      0, 0.08) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 1px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%) !important;
  -moz-background-size:200px 100px;
  background-size:200px 100px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
```